# Accessing Variables in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I do a `console.log` on the variable `event.body` it shows `article_url=http%3A%2F%2Fow.ly%2Fjo2n30fdI3y`

How can I access the value of `article_url`
In other words, I want to access `http%3A%2F%2Fow.ly%2Fjo2n30fdI3y`

Comment: Where is this coming from? Is it like a url query?

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually want to decode the percent encoded characters too, the best way is to use the native node.js [querystring module](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html#querystring_querystring_parse_str_sep_eq_options):

```
const body = require( 'querystring' ).parse( event.body );
const article_url = body.article_url;    
console.log( article_url );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(event.body.split('=')[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest approach is probably the following:

```js
var input = "article_url=http%3A%2F%2Fow.ly%2Fjo2n30fdI3y";
var output = input.split("=")[1];

console.log(output) // "http%3A%2F%2Fow.ly%2Fjo2n30fdI3y"
```